# HSLA effect with fixed menu

Tags: html, css

Please find my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/kbvwpo76/

I want to create a **fixed menu** on the top of the page with a `hsla` effect.
In the link above you can find an example with some random content.

My issue now is that the content starts right *behind* the menu.
However, I want that the content starts **below** the menu and when I scroll down the menu remains fixed whereas the content disappears behind the menu.

What do I have to change in the code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the header inside a normally positioned element with height set.

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <div class="navigation_desktop">
    <div class="button_desktop_01">1.0 Main Menu </div>
    <div class="button_desktop_01">2.0 Main Menu </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navigation_desktop{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 2%;
    position: fixed;
}

.button_desktop_01{
     float: left;
     width: 20%;
     cursor: pointer;
     background: hsla(0, 100%, 50%, 0.5);
 }
.nav-wrapper {
     height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks a lot for your help. Maybe you also have a solution for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658889/image-in-one-line-with-a-fixed-navigation